# Регулярка всего кроме русских букв и цифр

Tags: php

Помогите составить регулярку,которая удаляет все кроме русских,латинских букв и цифр,а также оставить пробелы...
Например,вот эта делает как надо,но удаляет пробелы:
`$result = preg_replace('/[^a-zа-яё]+/iu', '', $text);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = preg_replace('/[^a-zа-яё\s0-9]+/iu', '', $text);
// Где \s - это пробел, 0-9 - это цифры
или
$result = preg_replace('/[^\w\d\s]+/iu','',$text);
```

**[Проверка](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/adf76caecfac34867969435ab7d3cdd5734ca210)**

Comment: Ваша регулярка не берёт цифры, по-моему.

Comment: Ваша регулярка, как мне кажется, сломается на на такой строке `#3#`. А именно, второй `#` он не загребёт.

Comment: Здорово. А не могли бы объяснить, почему эта штука работает без глобального модификатора `g`?

Comment: @LEQADA `preg_replace ( mixed pattern, mixed replacement, mixed subject [, int limit] )` - если `limit` не указан или равняется -1, то будут заменены все вхождения шаблона. [Информация](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30372/discussion-between-leqada-and-alex).